# customer selection: find or create

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, interface

I'm working on a form to create offers for our customers. Sales is currently creating loads of duplicates because the search performance is poor and they are rather hitting the create button than look up an existing customer. Moving to elastic, offering a much better search experience, I want to disaccustom them from doing that.

My idea would be to decrease the presence of the create option by nesting it inside the search results (Option B).

[image]

What do you think?

Comment: You could do it as following : User types for example **google** in customer field. Then your field would be looking for google or **%google%** (wildcard). If anything like google is found give him the option to select that, if google is correctly spelled let him insert it, if google isnt found ask him if he wants to create a new customer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input @Tomm ! So basically like the feature here when you're posting something new. I'll  I'm just a little bit worried that they won't even try to search and just call the helpdesk instead.

Comment: You force them upon searching it? You wont allow them to make a new one unless they have input something. If the system cant find input insert it.

Comment: Well, if they know for sure that the customer isn't in the system, I've no problem that they create a new one. I just want to stop their bad habbit of creating customers without even looking them up first. That's why I thought making the create button less visible could be a soft approach to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your workflow / logic rather then switching interfaces.

Your current approach is almost correct but I would change a few things up to force users in a supportive way.

I would keep the input basic before focus, this only gives you 1 option (let your users input a customer).

[image: Step 1]

On focus :

[image: Step 2]

Once your user inputs a customer check if this user exists (if you do the backend, use jquery or something along those lines).

If user exists :

[image: Step 3]

If the user does not exist **then** let the user add it.

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Tomm.
We are using elastic for typeahead results while the user is entering a part of the customer name. The case in your wireframe, where no result is being returned, is not very likely. I will consider your suggestions and post the outcome and/or test results. (Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to vote you up...)